# Bangla characters change when copied over to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm having trouble with Photoshop correctly displaying Bangla characters.

Here is an example.

The correct original text is this: বিক্রি

But in Photoshop, it shows up like this: [image]

I have no idea why this is happening. I couldn't find anything useful from a Google search.

Answer (score 1):

To get Indic scripts to work in Photoshop CC, you need to enable the "World Ready Layout" option in *Preferences > Type*.  Once you have enabled it, it will only take effect for newly created documents. I may be wrong, but I don't think you can apply the option for documents you have already created, which is a bit of a bummer.

[image]

Here's an example showing that it works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, as it's not a language I know, but it looks like you need to enable right to left text in your text box.

You need to enable World-Ready Layout & Middle-Eastern features, then you can set it to Right to Left.

[image]

There's a fuller explanation on Adobe's Help - https://helpx.adobe.com/cy_en/photoshop/using/arabic-hebrew.html

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Thanks for the tip though.